# How to call PL SQL function that returns cursor in JasperReports?

Tags: oracle, plsql, jasper-reports

How to call PL SQL function that returns cursor in JasperReports (I'm using Jaspersoft Studio)?

Note: It's NOT a procedure with out parameter that returns a cursor.

I tried it in 2 ways:

First one:

```
select * FROM TABLE (fs_sorter_error_r.sorter_cntr_error('W6','03-MAY-2017',' 03-MAY-2017','967',20001))
```

that return s ERROR `cannot access rows from non nested tables`

Second one:

```
select fs_sorter_error_r.sorter_cntr_error('W6','03-MAY-2017',' 03-MAY-2017','967',20001)t1 from dual
```

which executes without error but returns one field t1 as oracle resultset which does not display anything.